# Not able to print the variable in windows batch file that stores an extracted value from CSV file

Tags: file, batch-file

Below is my code and i am not able to print the variable in windows batch file that stores an extracted value from CSV file

```
 @echo off
    Set _InputFile=D:\TH_Scripts\InputParamTest.csv
    for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%_InputFile%) do (
        set the_line=%%A
        goto process_line
    )

    :process_line
    echo i am here 
    pause
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=[,]" %%1 in (%the_line%) do (
        set hexcode=%%1
        set country=%%2
        set reg=%%3
        set owner=%%4
        set callsign=%%5
        set planetype=%%6
        set model=%%7 
        set THISLINE=%hexcode%,%country%,%reg%,%owner%,%callsign%,%planetype%,%model%
        echo %THISLINE% > %THEOUTPUTFILE%
    pause
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=[,]" %%1 in (%the_line%) do (`

%%number is not supported by batch syntax. `%n` means "the nth parameter to the procedure".

change `%%1` to `%%a`. The variables assigned are then `%%a`, `%%b` etc. to `%%g` note case is important. `%%a` can be `%%i` if you like - the values extracted are then assigned to `%%i`..`%%o`

2.

You need to search for innumerable articles on `delayed expansion` on SO. The value of `%var%` within a code block (parenthesised series of instructions) will be the value that the variable had when the code block was encountered - **not** the value as it is varied in the block (the "run-time" value)

To extract the run-time value, you need to first invoke `delayedexpansion` mode by executing a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` instruction (usually done directly after the initial `@echo off`) and then access the run-time value of the  variable by using `!var!`.

3. That having been said, unless you are actually using the variables you are establishing in the block, you can directly output your list using `%%a`, etc, not `%hexcode%` or `!hexcode!`. Without further information about how you intend to use these variables elsewhere, this may or may not be useful in your case.

BTW - 1,2,3... is not incorrect syntax, but 1-7 is shorter and means the same in this context.